# Singular in MuMIn::dredge

Tags: singular, mumin

I'm about to run a glm model to test my hypothesis.
Once I ran the model I got a singularity warning massage:
`glmakde_mdDredge <- lmer(log(akdearea) ~ 1 + age_binary + sex + trimester_number + Year + trackNightnum + mean_max_displacement.s + meanIIV_md.s + (1|Ring_ID), data = HRfullData, REML = F)`

```
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

I ran MuMIn::dredge on this model

```
options(na.action = 'na.fail')
dreModelsScore <- MuMIn::dredge(glmakde_mdDredge)


Fixed term is "(Intercept)"
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

Summary did give results.

My question is whether despite the warning messages the model ran all the possible options (including the singularity ones) or only on the models where there is no singularity problem?

Answer (score 0):

If a fitting function gives only a warning, and the value is a valid model object, it is included in the result (usually such models have suspicious  likelihood or coefficient values). You can convert warnings to errors with `option(warn = 2)` which will exclude from the `dredge` result fits by which a warning was issued.